# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm trying to get the controller's "destroy" to work correctly and I'm wondering what the correct set up should be.

The error that I'm getting is

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AuthenticationsController#destroy
Couldn't find Authentication without an ID
```

My controller looks like

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base
def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    redirect_to(:back)
end
```

database table

```
 create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "token"
  end
```

I have tried other parameters such as :user_id
How can I get users to destroy their tokens? (with the option to re-authenticate later)

Comment: it sounds like params[:id] isn't working properly, try manually adding a number that you know is an appropriate ID to see if it works e.g. current_user.authentications.find(2)

Comment: it works when I manually add in an authentication id, how can i fix this?

Comment: How are you executing the request? Something is wrong with your link URL or however you are reaching the destroy method.

Comment: As Logan said, the params[:id] is not being passed correctly.  Maybe post that code on here so we can take a look

Comment: this is what I have in view `<%= link_to "Disconnect Your Authentication", "/auth/disconnect" %>` ... and in my routes, I have `match '/auth/disconnect', :to => 'authentications#destroy'`

Comment: You are not passing a param to the controller with that request. Depending on your requirements though, you may not need to. Can you simply destroy all the authentications with `current_user.authentications.destroy_all`?

Comment: no that gives me this error `undefined method 'destroy'`

Comment: Actually if I just do this, it seems to work. `def destroy
 current_user.authentications.destroy_all end`. Is this code okay to use?

Comment: If you want to destroy all of the current user's authentications... then yes

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing id to controller

try

```
<%= link_to "Disconnect Your Authentication", {:controller=>'authentications', :action=>'destroy', :id=>current_user.authentication_id} %>
```

or use path helper with @autentication argument as option.

(You will need to edit your routes file)

Comment: Path helpers are the way to go

Comment: mm... i quite often use first option when I need to pass some additional params, is it somehow not good way?

Comment: It's just my opinion. I think path helpers can make unit testing and refactoring a bit easier. But probably not enough to say one way is good and the other is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to destroy all authentications for a user, you could certainly change your controller's destroy method to be:

```
def destroy
  current_user.authentications.destroy_all
end
```

A more conventional approach would be to destroy a particular authentication.  In that case the `link_to` method needs a path that includes an id parameter (which will end up as your `params[:id]` value in the controller).  You can imagine a view snippet like the following that displays all a user's authentications, each with a destroy link:

```
<ul>
<% current_user.authentications.each do |a| %>
  <li>
    <%= a.provider %>
    - 
    <%= link_to 'Disconnect Your Authentication', authentication_path(a), :method => :delete %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This assumes current_user is a helper and that your routes are set up on your authentication model.  The `authentication_path` helper uses the `a` authentication instance to generate a path, complete with an id parameter.